# Change of variables $x=u+v$, $y=u-v$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to calculate $ \displaystyle \int _0 ^ 1 \int_y^ 1 (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2) dx \;  dy $ making the changes of variables $x = u + v, y = u-v$

I know $|Jg(x)|=2$ and $f(g)=2(u^2+v^2)$

I'm stuck, I don't know how to raise the new integral

Answer (score 1):

$x = u + v, y = u-v$

$u = \frac{x+y}{2}, v = \frac{x-y}{2}$

Given the original region, note that  $ \ 0 \leq x-y \leq 1$

i.e $ \ 0 \leq v \leq \frac{1}{2}$

For any value of $v$, the limts of $u$ will be,

$v \leq u \leq 1-v$

So the new integral is

$\displaystyle \int _0^{1/2} \int_{v}^{1-v} 2 (u^2 + v^2) \ |J| \ du \ dv$