# Calculate $\int_D(x+y)dA$ in two ways

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

Let D be a triangle with corners at (0,0), (1,0) and (1,1). To integrate this without substitution  I found: $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq x$. So I will skip the evaluation part because its pretty easy for me.  Now this is the part where I am stuck. My calculus books wants me to do a substitution $x = u + v$ and $y = u - v$. I have some trouble with finding the bounds for the new integral, I already saw an answer on the site but it pas posted with little to no explanation.

this is the other post where I don't understand how they found the bounds of u: [Change of variables $x=u+v$, $y=u-v$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4010435/change-of-variables-x-uv-y-u-v)

Comment: Can you please insert in your post a link to the "answer on the site" you saw? Anyway, the bounds are $0\le v\le u,\;u+v\le1$ (simply replacing $x,y$ by $u+v,u-v$ in the original bounds).

Comment: I still don't realy get it and besides, it isn't integratable right now right? Either u or v need to be bounded by real numbers not variables if I remember correct

Comment: I edited it now.

Comment: These inequalities define a domain which is not a rectangle. The original ones did the same ($y$ was bounded by $x$).

Comment: Yeah I know but in your answer v and u are both bounded by v or u while in the original x is bounded by 0 and 1

Comment: It's a linear transformation, so you just need to figure out where in the $uv$-plane the three corners are mapped; that gives you the corners of a new triangle to integrate over in the $uv$-plane.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\iint_{0\le y\le x\le1}(x+y)dxdy&=\iint_{0\le v\le u,\;u+v\le1}(2u)(2dudv)\\&=4\int_0^{1/2}\left(\int_v^{1-v}udu\right)dv\\&=\dots\\&=\frac12.\end{align}$$